# How to make netcat receive packet many times?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netcat

1. On netcat server

   nc -lu 80 >> test.out
2. On netcat client, send UDP packet

   echo -n foo | nc -u -w 1 {server_IP} 80
3. Repeat step 2 again, but I see netcat client cli hangs there...

Without closing netcat server, I expect it can receive 5 UDP packets after the client do 5 times, like:

```
cat test.out
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

But the server seems to just receive one time

```
cat test.out
foo
```

and the client hangs...

How can I make netcat server receive many udp packets consecutively.

Comment: See my answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/1087732/63361

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `nc -kluvw 0 localhost 9000` on the server.